# Are there any downloadable samples of 48 fps video?

Tags: video, video-quality

I would like to compare 24fps to 48fps video, but haven't been able to find any video samples.

Does anyone know of such samples?  Being able to compare the same video at several framerates would be lovely!

Comment: You could also make your own in an app like Motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short mov to demonstrate the difference, that's all I've been able to find:

http://www.stopmotionpro.com/media/video/48fps_cameramove2.mov

Comment: That's helpful, thanks.  I hope to eventually be able to compare some movie footage, to see what's the big deal about The Hobbit being 48 fps.

Comment: That video wasn't in 48 fps. It may have been filmed that way, but wasn't uploaded. 48 fps is much more drastic looking. Some people like it, but the more you know about film, higher frame rates will bug the hell out of you.